# PHP-CLI Docker with extension

Tags: php, docker

I want to run php file with one line docker run command.
`docker run  -v "$PWD":/home -w /home php:5.6-fpm php /home/irc_bot.php`
It actually works but within the target file, I use `socket_create()`, and I got the error `"Call to undefined function socket_create()"`.

Here I'd love to enable it in php.ini. Is it possible? or Do you not a better way to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

You should create own conteiner with needed extentions.